# Vue template not being displayed?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to vue and I am trying to get a simple component to display in a div. I am using laravel 5.4 with laravel mix and vue version 2.6.6 to display a vue component.

this is the div in my view file:

```
<div id="sidenav"> </div>
```

This is my app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('SideNav', require('./components/SideNav.vue').default);

var SideNav = new Vue({
    el: '#sidenav'
});
```

This is SideNav.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'SideNav'
    }
</script>
```

There aren't any errors with npm install, npm build, npm run dev, or npm run watch. On the page I do not see

## Test

I'm sorry for such a newb question, but this has been driving me crazy for a few hours.

Comment: Try changing your template to include the SideNav component `<div id="sidenav"> <SideNav/></div>` or `<div id="sidenav"> <div is="SideNav"></div></div>`

Comment: @Connor I get the same result when I add `<div id="sidenav"> <SideNav/></div>` inside my template of my SideNav file. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

```html
<div id="sidenav">
    <SideNav></SideNav>
</div>
```

---

You "mount" your Vue instance to the root element with id `#sidenav` here:

```js
var SideNav = new Vue({
    el: '#sidenav'
});
```

meaning, when you created your Vue component here: `Vue.component('SideNav', require('./components/SideNav.vue'));`, you have access to the `<SideNav>` tag **within that root element**.

Also, I'm not sure if you need the `.default` at the end of your `Vue.component(...)` creation.

Comment: Thanks for your response but making both changes you suggested had no effect.